# removeFolder doesn't work

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I'm not sure what is wrong with my script.

```
var folderToDelete = DriveApp.getFoldersByName('folderName').next();
DriveApp.removeFolder(folderToDelete);
```

It doesn't show errors and the folder is not removed

It's sure the folder with name 'folderName' exists

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`removeFolder` just removes the folder from the root of the drive. From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#removeFolder(Folder)):

> Removes the given folder from the root of the user's Drive. **This
>   method does not delete the folder** or its contents, but if a folder is
>   removed from all of its parents, it **cannot be seen in Drive except by
>   searching for it or using the "All items" view**.

Are you looking for [`setTrashed()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#setTrashed(Boolean))?

```
folderToDelete.setTrashed(true)
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks. I've tried for setTrashed with the same result. And there is only one folder with that name. Question setTrashed must be setTrashed(true) ?? Is it necessary to set it trashed before removeFolder?? Thanks!

Comment: yes, should have a true argument. So even if you run setTrashed the folder is not in the trash? Did you debug the script? Is it capturing any folders with the first command? try `Logger.log(DriveApp.getFoldersByName('folderName').hasNext())`

Comment: Ok. Trashed. I hadn't set (true). But the folder isn't removed. The explanation is in your quoted sentence from developers docum. Thanks.